# Change IP dynamic on each ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, ip, developer-console

I am trying to executive an ajax request in the console , Is it possible to change our IP on each ajax call ???? , here is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/mycustomsite/",
            data: {
                'data1': 1,
                'data2': '84',
                'data3': 0
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(resPonseTxt) {

            },
            error: function() {

            }
        })

;
```

the problem is that the url:  mycustomsite is note down  our IP and stop the call on another ajax call . i would like to change IP on each ajax call so that i can run my ajax call multiple times

Comment: `to change our IP` - if you have an internet service with dynamic IP, disconnect the internet and reconnect your internet between each request ... though, some dynamic IP's are less dynamic than others - I've had the same dynamic IP for a year with several disconnections ... hope this helps

Comment: you can't do it via javascript. You must reconfigure your browser/system to use different proxy

Comment: seeing as `url: "/mycustomsite/"` is same domain of your page, you therefore have access to the server side code ... change the code so you can do multiple requests from the same IP - seems obvious when you think about it

Comment: `to use different proxy` - if you use a proxy, make sure it's not one that sends X-REQUESTED-FOR (or something like that) - because any decent server will look for that to get the actual requesting IP in the case of a proxied request - anonymous proxy is what you want in that case

Comment: @Jaromanda X . In don't have server access . url: "/mycustomsite/"  is not    accessible .

Comment: @Adam Wolski How can i reconfigure my  browser/system to use different proxy to get my work done

Comment: well, either use the changing proxy, or reset your internet connection to get a new IP address ...

Comment: `How can i reconfigure my browser/system to use different proxy` - depends on your browser, they all have proxy settings in the configuration ... note, it's a manual configuration, not one that can be changed in javascript

Comment: @Jaromanda X   is it to automate the process using javascript and console

Comment: automate? you may be able to automate your router so it gets a new IP address for you - but that's beyond your abilities ... nothing about changing proxy or IP address can be "automated" in a browser

Comment: @JaromandaX he can ajax a local node js server that changes the proxy address in the system though

Comment: yeah ... easy peasy

Comment: @Adam Wolski  . so i am guessing this is not possible . :(